# Getting timestamps in IBM Watson unity SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson

How can I access timestamps of words in IBM Watson Speech to Text Unity SDK?

This is the code snippet I am using. I am able to get the correct transcript for a given audio but the timestamps **variable remains Null**.

```
[SerializeField]
private AudioClip m_AudioClip = new AudioClip();
private SpeechToText m_SpeechToText = new SpeechToText();

void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("start");
    m_SpeechToText.EnableTimestamps = true;

    m_SpeechToText.Recognize(m_AudioClip, OnRecognize);
}

void OnRecognize(SpeechRecognitionEvent result)
{

    Debug.Log("Here");
    if (result != null && result.results.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (var res in result.results)
        {
            foreach (var alt in res.alternatives)
            {
                var timestamps = alt.timestamps;
                Debug.Log(timestamps);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find timestamps in the SpeechRecognitionAlternatives object.

```
void OnRecognize(SpeechRecognitionEvent result)
{

    Debug.Log("Here");
    if (result != null && result.results.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (var res in result.results)
        {
            foreach (var alt in res.alternatives)
            {
                if (alt.Timestamps != null)
                    foreach (var timestamp in alt.Timestamps)
                        Debug.Log(string.Format("timestamp word: {0}, start: {1}, end: {2}", timestamp.Word, timestamp.Start, timestamp.End));
            }
        }
    }
}
```